# How to get int from NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

**Update**

I don't want to use XML parser because this is all the string. Very small, so, no parser please. Thanks.

---

I have a XML string like this: `<AppVersion>5</AppVersion>`. Now I want to get that `5`. How can do it?

Note that `5` could also be `50`. I mean the length will change.

Comment: If this string is part of a larger XML document, have you tried the the XML parsing API?

Comment: If you have an XML string, use an XML parser.

Comment: @BergQuester This is all the string. All, so I don't want to use XML parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
NSString *string = @"<AppVersion>50</AppVersion>";
NSError *error;

// this looks for any sequence of digits between 0 and 9 between those two tags

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<AppVersion>([0-9]+)</AppVersion>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];
if (error)
    NSLog(@"%s: regularExpressionWithPattern error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSString *result = [string substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
```

Or you could use a scanner:

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:nil];
NSInteger i;
if ([scanner scanInteger:&i])
    NSLog(@"%d", i);
```

Comment: I like the scanner solution. Also the regular expression is excellent way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have the string and are looking for an easy way to extract the number.  This can be done with a few lines of code.  We know the starting point, because it's a constant.  The ending point can vary depending on the length of the number.

```
NSString *xml=@"<AppVersion>5</AppVersion>";
int start=12; // Constant
NSRange end = [xml rangeOfString:@"</"]; // Depends on length

NSString *aNum = [xml substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start, end.location-start)];
NSLog(@"%@", aNum);
```

Three examples to show that it works in the general case:

```
// Test 5
NSString *xml=@"<AppVersion>5</AppVersion>";
int start=12; // Constant
NSRange end = [xml rangeOfString:@"</"]; // Depends on length

NSString *aNum = [xml substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start, end.location-start)];
NSLog(@"%@", aNum);

// Test 500
xml=@"<AppVersion>500</AppVersion>";
end = [xml rangeOfString:@"</"]; // Depends on length

aNum = [xml substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start, end.location-start)];
NSLog(@"%@", aNum);

// Test 500000
xml=@"<AppVersion>500000</AppVersion>";
end = [xml rangeOfString:@"</"]; // Depends on length

aNum = [xml substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start, end.location-start)];
NSLog(@"%@", aNum);
```

Comment: Your answer works but I think Rob's is better. Thank you, vote up.

Answer (score 0):

I have my own category to get value from XML
But you can try to use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't want to use XML parser. I think there's no need for a so small task.